# How to click language/region link using Selenium Webdriver and Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to just click 'North America' and 'US', at the following URL:
http://www.nike.com/language_tunnel

Here are the steps I have were working for a few weeks, but now seem to not work.

```
# choose country/region
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]").click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.US a"))).click()
```

The first command now seems to open South America and then it stalls because it is looking for US, but there is no US link under South America.
I believe I need to change the xPath, but I'm not sure what is the correct xpath (and would prefer to not use xpath at all).

Comment: Expecting you to mark the correct answer that solves your problem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, locating the element by index in this case is not quite reliable. Things like the order of elements tend to change frequently. Instead, use the `data-region` attribute, for instance:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-region=n-america]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-region="n-america"]').click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li  a[data-country="US"]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you might want to change the country name tomorrow, you can use the following snippet :

```
countryToSearch = "North America"  // you can change this accordingly, rest should work fine
for countries in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])"):
    countryName = countries.text
    if countryName == countryToSearch:
        countries.click()
        break
```